# Badge Icon doesn't increase when getting PushNotification in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an Application with Apple push notifications but problem is that when push arrives, the badge app icon doesn't get incremented.

Can anyone tell me how to increment the badge of app?

I am using the following code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo {
    NSString* alertValue = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"my message-- %@",alertValue);
    int badgeValue= [alertValue intValue];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+ badgeValue];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot send `++` in the push notification. You need to provide an exact badge count in the push notification payload, and manage the badge count on the server side.

Comment: You need to have a database of each user, and remember the count. I don't know what your application does specifically, but you need to think how implement. For example, a message app, increases the badge count on server with every new message, and sets it to 0 when the user opens the app.

Comment: we set following code in php code.

{"aps" : {
 "alert" : "This is the alert text",
 "badge" : 1,
 "sound" : "default"
 }
}

Comment: I also try with +1 but nothing happend? How can I increment it?

Comment: You need to have a database, increase in database and when you build the payload, you need to set the correct number (1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or ...).

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber
numberOfBadges +=1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];
```

Answer (score 0):

Leo is right about how to do what you want.

The thing to know is, that whatever code you have does not matter.  That code only gets activated if the application is open when the push notification is received.  If the app is not open, no code is run.

Another possibility you might want to look into is a data-only push, that contains the increment you want for the badge in a non-APS metadata block.  Then you could arbitrarily specify an increment in a data push and code would be activated to handle the contents.  But it's very likely you really need to do what Leo suggests, otherwise how will you know the right amount to increment the badge by?